# How to do @e[!score_Blank_min=1]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command on my server that affect everyone except someone with a certain score:

`@e[r=2,type=!score_Assassin8Craiy_min=1]`. 
I'm trying as much as I can but I'm no professional. Please help.

Comment: That selector doesn't make much sense.  Are you trying to specify a type?  Is `Assassin8Craiy` the name of the scoreboard objective?

Comment: I need more information. What command are you trying to do? /effect?

Comment: @WolfySocks Why is your leaderboard stat named Assassin8Craiy I would of named it something more simple.   What is in the other command block?   If your trying to use a effect command there has to be another command block so what is in it and is the command you showed above a testfor command?

Answer (score 1):

```
@e[r=2,score_Assassin8Craiy_min=1]
```

Everyone that's got the score of 1 or more

```
@e[r=2,score_Assassin8Craiy=0]
```

Everyone that's got the score of 0 or less.

```
'_min=X' -> Minimum score || '=X' Maximum score
```

And `type` is for types of entities... like `type=Creeper`

Answer (score 0):

You want a command that "affects everyone except someone with a certain score". You're using the selector `@e[r=2,type=!score_Assassin8Craiy_min=1]`. To help you learn, I'll explain what you did wrong, and end with the final selector.

- Use @a instead of @e. @e targets all entities, @a targets all players.
- `r=2` will only target things within 2 blocks of your player (or the command block). Remove this if you want to target everyone.
- You're using `type=!score_Assassin8Craiy_min=1`. This is very wrong:

  The `type` at the beginning will search for types of entities, e.g. Player, Item, Zombie, Enderman. It's not used for score detection - remove it.

  `score_Assassin8Craiy_min=1` This will target everything which has a score of at least 1 on the scoreboard named "Assassin8Craiy". This seems like a rather odd name for a scoreboard; I expect that you've mistaken it for a player name.

  Before using a scoreboard, you must set it up with `scoreboard objectives add *objectiveName* dummy`. Replace *objectiveName* with a descriptive name for your scoreboard. This is the same name that you should be using in the middle of `score_*objectiveName*_min=1`.

  Don't forget to actually give a player a score of at least 1 with the command `scoreboard players add *playerName* *objectiveName* 1`. Replace *playerName* with a player's full name and *objectiveName* with the name of the scoreboard objective that you set in the previous paragraph.

The completed selector should look something like `@a[type=score_Objective_min=1]`.